# PyQT manage cursor shape manually

Tags: python, pyqt5

I know how to set mouse cursor shape in PyQt, however ss it possible in PyQt to have all of what mouse cursor shape does, to be disabled, e.g. when it hovers over line edit, it has one cursor shape, when it hovers over empty widget it has regular shape, when it hovers the edge of draggable widget it has different shape. I want it all disabled globlally and manage that manually. Are there simple ways to do this, or do I have to reimplement hoverEvent for every widget and so on?

Comment: What you seem to be asking is how to set the cursor theme for the whole application. Qt has APIs for changing the *icon theme*, but that does not include cursors, which are instead either supplied by the system or fall back to hard-coded defaults. However, if your application only needs to run on Linux (i.e. X11), it should be possible to override this default behaviour by manipulating some environment variables. Otherwise, you will have to implement everything yourself.